# How to catch "parse error" when installing app which contains minSdkVersion as 21?

Tags: android, parse-error

I made one android application which contains the minimum sdk version (ie.,**minSdkVersion 21**).

When i'm trying to run that app on the mobile, that mobile contains only the OS version of just Jellybeans(***SDK version is 18***).and it saying like "**PARSE ERROR**".
Here what i wanted is,i want to catch this error and tell them to the end users  like "this app won't support your device" by dialog.How to overcome this issue?

Suggestions please !...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is thrown when the apk is corrupted, so you cannot catch this exception in your app.[Read this for more info.](http://www.smarttricks.net/fix-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package)